# the given list is from user input, can we solve whether is it a prime number or not using list comprehension

Tags: python-3.x

```py
num = int (input('Enter the Number : '))
if (num <=1):
  print (num,'is not a prime number')
else:
  for i in range (2,num):
      if (num%i)==0:
       print (num,'is not a prime number')
       break
  else:
    print (num,'is prime number')
```

Comment: What error are you getting? What output do you expect? What is your question?

Comment: no error is display but performance wise comprehension meathod is fast, i could not convert above code in list comprehension

Comment: If you choose the comprehension list, what would the list contain? Because list comprehension returns a list :)

Comment: You could gain some "speed" by restricting your search to `num/2` or  even `math.sqrt(num)`

Comment: Actualy above code i want conver in comprehension method, how to do

Answer (score 0):

You could create a list of Boolean values that are True if and only if the index `i` is a divisor of `num`. Then the sum over that list is zero if and only if `num` is a prime number:

```py
num = int(input('Enter the number: '))

if (num <= 1):
    print (num, 'is not a prime number.')
else:
    divisors = [(num % i) == 0 for i in range(2, num)]
    if sum(divisors) > 0:
        print (num, 'is not a prime number.')
    else:
        print (num, 'is a prime number.')
```